What's the difference between gitlab and gitlab runner while they're deployed at the custom server?
Am I right that gitlab service is like a controller (so it's reflected by gitlab-ctl) for gitlab-runner?
Gitlab service at Linux server in particular stores the configurations needed for gitlab-runner.
And if there's only gitlab-runner then it - in the absence of Gitlab - interacts with gitlab.com where IS configurations needed for work?

GitLab Runner is an application that works with GitLab CI/CD to run jobs in a pipeline.
By default these runners are enabled for all the projects. But yes, you can use Gitlab runner for the self managed projects as well.
For self manage runners, you need register your own runners on GitLab.com or on your own instance.
To use self-managed runners, you install GitLab Runner on infrastructure that you own or manage.
You can find the details about all the steps on the Gitlab docs.
